# cakephp and agency bootstrap template contact form always failing

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

Using the agency bootstrap template which comes with single php file that I would perfer not to use because I am using cakephp.
I am using cakephp version 2 and have a message folder with crud section for admin to login into and use.
The landing page uses the PagesController and the message section has its own MessagesController. The controller i am trying to access when completing the form.
I have narrowed it down to the contact_me.js file which has nice form validation and error messages that I would like to use. If I use the contact_me.js file it always fails but when I dont use it messages are saved.
 On line 22 the url seems to be incorrect and I don't know how to write it correctly. Is that the issue?
**contact form**

```
 <section id="contact">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                <h2 class="section-heading">Contact Us</h2>
                <h3 class="section-subheading text-muted">Want to know more or have any enquires please fill out the form below and we will get back to you.</h3>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
                 <?php echo $this->Form->create('Comment'); ?>
                <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate >

                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('name', array('id' => 'name', 'class' => 'form-control', "placeholder" => 'Enter your name here', 'required data-validation-required-message' => "Please enter your name", 'label' => false)); ?>

                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->input('email', array('id' => 'email', 'class' => 'form-control', "placeholder" => 'Enter your email here', 'required data-validation-required-message' => "Please enter your email", 'type' => "email", 'label' => false)); ?>

                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                               <?php echo $this->Form->input('phone', array('id' => 'phone', 'class' => 'form-control', "placeholder" => 'Enter phone number here', 'required data-validation-required-message' => "Please enter your phone number", 'label' => false)); ?>

                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <?php echo $this->Form->textarea('comment', array('id' => 'comment', 'class' => 'form-control', "placeholder" => 'Your comment *', 'required data-validation-required-message' => 'Please enter a message', 'resize' => false, 'label' => false)); ?>

                                <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12 text-center">
                            <div id="success"></div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xl"><?php echo $this->Form->end(__('')); ?>Submit</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </form >
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**contact_me.js**

```
preventSubmit: true,
    submitError: function ($form, event, errors) {
        // additional error messages or events
    },
    submitSuccess: function ($form, event) {
        event.preventDefault(); // prevent default submit behaviour
        // get values from FORM

        var name = $("input#name").val();
        var email = $("input#email").val();
        var phone = $("input#phone").val();
        var comment = $("textarea#comment").val();
        var firstName = name; // For Success/Failure Message
        // Check for white space in name for Success/Fail message
        if (firstName.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {
            firstName = name.split(' ').slice(0, -1).join(' ');
        }
        $.ajax({
            url: "Comments/add",
            type: "post",
            data: {
                name: name,
                phone: phone,
                email: email,
                comment: comment
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                // Success message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-success'>");
                $('#success > .alert-success').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append("<strong>Your message has been sent. </strong>");
                $('#success > .alert-success')
                        .append('</div>');

                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            },
            error: function () {
                // Fail message
                $('#success').html("<div class='alert alert-danger'>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').html("<button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='alert' aria-hidden='true'>&times;")
                        .append("</button>");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append("<strong>Sorry " + firstName + ", it seems that my mail server is not responding. Please try again later!");
                $('#success > .alert-danger').append('</div>');
                //clear all fields
                $('#contactForm').trigger("reset");
            }
        });
    },
    filter: function () {
        return $(this).is(":visible");
    }
});

$("a[data-toggle=\"tab\"]").click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).tab("show");
});
```